# Which is the best way to iterate over a non-generic List?

Tags: java, loops, iteration, raw-types

I have to use an old piece of code where I have a List and I need to iterate over it. Foreach loop does not work. Which is the best and safest way to do this?

Example

```
private void process(List objects) {
    someloop {
        //do something with list item
        //lets assume objects in the List are instances of Content class
    }           
}
```

Comment: Why doesn't the for-each loop work?

Comment: Do you mean that you need to remove elements from the list, or do something else which prevents the usage of *for-each*? Please clarify.

Comment: I was trying the foreach loop with the Content class (not Object) and that's why it didn't work. My mistake, I didn't realize that. Thank you

Comment: What does **Foreach loop does not work** mean? This seems to be a candidate for low quality question flag.

Comment: So...first you say foreach loop does not work, do not explain what you mean by that and then accept an answer that uses foreach loop. This is has to be textbook definition of a low quality question.

Comment: @Hemal I'm sorry, it's a bad question. I'm overworked. Of course the foreach loop works, I just used it in a bad way. I flagged it a requested a delete.

Comment: @Tom no problem, we all make mistakes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `Iterator`:

```
Iterator iter = objects.iterator();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    Object element = iter.next();
}
```

Or better directly for-each:

```
for (Object obj : objects) {
}
```

Comment: Is an interator more efficient than a simple for() loop?

Comment: No difference. For-each uses iterator inside.

Answer (score 3):

Either use an iterator, if you need to be able to remove the current element from the list:

```
for (Iterator it = list.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
    Foo foo = (Foo) it.next();
    // ...
    it.remove();
}
```

Or use a foreach loop:

```
for (Object o : list) {
    Foo foo = (Foo) o;
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Fixed. Thank you. I prefer using a for loop, because it reduces the scope of the iterator to the loop.

Comment: Why do the it.remove() ? Could that lead to a concurrent access exception with some list implementations?

Comment: It's just to show why an iterator might be necessary: removing an element from a collection while iterating over it is only possible using an iterator. It's not possible with a foreach loop, and using iterator is the only way to avoid a ConcurrentModificationException. If remove is not necessary, the foreach loop is simpler and shorter.

Comment: @James DW - When using iterator you are allowed to remove elements if you wish. When using for-each loop you can't.